# Custom while loop in Haskell prints a statement twice

Tags: haskell, io, stdout, monads

I'm new to Haskell and have been trying to better understand the IO monad (after playing with pure functions for a while).

I'm following a tutorial on the [IO monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside#What_is_a_monad.3F)

One of the exercises is making a while function. They don't show an example so you can't check your answer.

Here is mine:

```
while :: IO Bool -> IO ()
while action = do p <- action
                  if p then putStrLn "You win!" >> return ()
                       else putStrLn "Nope. Try again!" >> while action


main = do putStrLn "Come and guess the letter!"
          while (constAskForC)
          where constAskForC = do c <- getChar
                                  return $ c == 'c'
```

Now, my issue is that if you enter a wrong character (pretty much a character that is not 'c'), then string "Nope. Try again!" gets printed twice to StdOut. Why is this? Here's the program running:

```
Come and guess the letter!


"Nope. Try again!"

"Nope. Try again!"
d
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"

"Nope. Try again!"

"Nope. Try again!"
a
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"
d
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"
f
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"
a
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"
s
"Nope. Try again!"
"Nope. Try again!"
```

If you just hit enter (enter no character) then it only gets printed once. Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: My initial guess is the buffering mode.  Try out `hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering` after importing `System.IO` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: You enter a letter and press enter. A letter is a character. Enter is another character. That gives two characters, count them ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `constAskForC` function. You use `getChar`, but that will only read one character. So you read c, and after you read `c`, you will get the end-of-line character (`\n`). There is really no way to get single characters, but you can get a whole line and only take the first character:

```
main = do putStrLn "Come and guess the letter!"
          while (constAskForC)
  where constAskForC = do c <- getLine
                          return $ case c of
                            [] ->     False -- There was no input              
                            'c':[] -> True -- The first letter was a c, and nothing else was entered
                            _      -> False -- Otherwise, the result is False
```

---

Another minor note on your code: `putStrLn "You win!" >> return ()` is the same as `putStrLn "You win!"`

Comment: Ahh, forgot that <ENTER> is a character. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is an interaction of the behaviour of the `getChar` command with the normal
buffering behaviour of a compiled program, which is to use line buffering.

The `getChar` command consumes only a single character. In particular, hitting return creates a newline character on its own.

However, with line buffering, no input will actually arrive before you enter a complete line.
So if you interleave a character and the Return key, two characters will be generated in one go, leading to the strange output.

You can fix this by adding the line

```
import System.IO
```

in the beginning and then adding the statement

```
hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
```

to the `main` program. Alternatively, use GHCi which uses `NoBuffering` by default.

Answer (score 2):

When you type a character and press enter that's actually two characters (the printable character plus a linefeed character). You probably want to use `getLine` instead.